# UnicodeEncodeError - How to output Russian characters in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, python-unicode

I'm trying to query data in a MongoDB database using pymongo. Some of the documents inside a collection have Russian characters as values such as "Л" "о" or "ч". Whenever I query for a document that has such characters I get the following output:

```
>>> pprint(db.mycollection.find_one({}))

{
  "_id" : ObjectId('123456')
  "name" : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: character maps to <undefined>
}
```

At first, I thought the "name" value was just corrupted. Therefore I logged on to MongoDb Atlas/Compass and searched for the user via "_id". (in the case above, I would search for ObjectId('123456')) and it successfully returned the document with name value in russian characters. I've looked around on stackoverflow aswell as try different encoding and decoding chains with utf8 and cp1252 but I am still getting the same error. Anyone have any thoughts as to what might be happening?

UPDATE: program works on windows terminal and correctly displays russian characters. However, I would like to explore how to build this using sublime. Here is the python3.sublime-build I am using to compile with sublime:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],

    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",

    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Additonally, print(sys.stdout.encoding) outputs cp1252 compiling with sublime but it outputs utf-8 compiling within the windows terminal.

Comment: You should be able to do `name = db.mycollection.find_one({})["name"]` to get mongodb out of the equation. Now `pprint(name)` fails. Then post `print(repr(name))` so we can see what it is. But in the end it looks like your terminal is "cp1252" (or similar) that just doesn't have a character representation for these letters. You could `print(sys.stdout.encoding)` to see. But the answer may be to get a utf-8 supporting terminal. What Operating System are you on?

Comment: @tdelaney Output for print(repr(name)):  " Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\antho\OneDrive\Desktop\dir1\main.py", line 75, in <module>
    print(repr(name))
  File "C:\Users\antho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1-3: character maps to <undefined>    "

Comment: @tdelaney Output for print(sys.stdout.encoding) : cp1252 . Operating system is windows 10. Working on Sublime text 3 with python 3.9

Comment: I don't have Windows up at the moment, but perhaps you can move to Windows Terminal https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab to solve the problem.

Comment: @tdelaney Hey, that actually works, however I will keep the post up just incase anybody else can help solve it with sublime. Additionally print(sys.stdout.encoding) actually outputs "utf-8" now so that's interesting.

Comment: Yes, its two things -the encoding needed to get the string from your program to the terminal and the terminal expanding it into unicode to find the right gliphs to put on screen. I'm debating whether to make this the answer because I'm not sure what the support in the standard console is. I could swear it worked for me last time I tried. But there a many subversions of Win 10 and unicode support has changed, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Adding two lines to the sublime-build worked for me:

```
{
  "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.python",
  "encoding": "utf8",
  "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8", "LANG": "en_US.UTF-8"},
}
```